# Spring cache not being used after Cache evict on schedule

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I have a repository class as follows:

```
@EnableCaching
@EnableScheduling
@Repository("dao")
public class CustomerDao implements CustomerDao<Customer> {
    //...

    @Cacheable(value = "customers")
    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAll() {
        LOG.info("in getALL() method");
        return this.jdbcTemplate.query(this.QUERY_ALL_CUSTOMER, new CustomerRowMapper());
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "customers", allEntries = true)
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 60000L)
    public void refreshAllCustomers() {
        LOG.info("Refreshing Customers");
        getAll();
        LOG.info("Refreshing Customers Finished");
    }
}
```

When I call the api that calls `getAll()` first time, it takes time as expected.
When I call `getAll()` again, it is fast as result is returned from cache as expected.

However, on schedule, I call the `refreshAllCustomers()` to clear the cache and re-populate it using `getAll()` call in which case I expect the result to be cached again.

After the call to `refreshAllCustomers()` , it seems that any calls to `getAll()` runs the query and not returning the results from the cache itself.

Any ideas why this is happening? Am I missing a config or not doing something correctly.

Comment: What AOP provider you're using? If it's proxies, then calling `getAll()` from the same component bypasses the caching interceptor.

Comment: I am using spring. I am not sure if there is a cleaner way to get around this other than using `@Autowired`  this repo class itself

Answer (score 0):

`@CacheEvict` it takes effect after the method is executed.After the `refreshAllCustomers ()` method is executed, the cache is cleared.If you want to use the `@CacheEvict` annotation to invalidate the cache before the method is executed, you can try `@CacheEvict (value = customers, before Invocation = true)`

Comment: I tried with `beforeinvocation=true`, same issue. It is more related to proxy bypass as stated by  M. Prokhorov in the comments.

Comment: he is right. you can try injecting Cache Manager to create and destroy caches manually.

Comment: In fact, injecting a cache manager would be a preferred approach. Since there is already an intent to do a manual refresh anyway - it should not rely on annotation-driven controls anymore. Because annotations are intended exactly for the reason of not having to do anything manually.

Comment: can you point me to an example with `CacheManager` or include as an answer?